# Javascript: setTimeout: clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I wrote a generic waitFor function that would take the callback and a wait time and wait for it. From my understanding and observation, my code would wait for the whole time and then report status. I want to clear the timeout once the resolve is hit. How do I do that?

```
    var _timer;
    function waitForGeneric(method, max) {
    var start = Date.now();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        method();
        function check() {
            result = _connected;
            if (result) {
                console.log('connected to server[connection status]: ' + result);
                window.clearTimeout(_timer);
                resolve();
            }            
            else {
                if (Date.now() - start > max) {
                    console.log('waited for 30 seconds for connection[connection status]: ' + result);
                    reject();
                }
                else {
                    timer = window.setTimeout(check, 1000);
                }
            }
        }

        check();

    });
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Basically yes, and you can use it without `window` in your example. Both `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. And also you need to assign `setTimeout` to `_timer`, not `timer`

Comment: typo, missing underscore: `timer = window.setTimeout(check, 1000);` to `_timer = setTimeout(...`

Comment: @Mister Jojo: You saved me! I

Comment: And @tarkh, thank you for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

I won't be able to respond further to this until tomorrow, and I don't necessarily have the tools to test what you are trying to do to make sure this is what you are going for... but if you want to run a function after a promise is resolved, you can attach the `.then()` method to the promise instance. Also, I could be wrong for your specific case, but I typically don't see `window.clearTimeout` or `window.setTimeout`, but rather they just have their respective function calls as `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout`.

```js
var _timer;
function waitForGeneric(method, max)
{
  var start = Date.now();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    method();
    function check() {
        result = _connected;
        if (result) {
            console.log('connected to server[connection status]: ' + result);
            clearTimeout(_timer);
            resolve();
        }            
        else {
            if (Date.now() - start > max) {
                console.log('waited for 30 seconds for connection[connection status]: ' + result);
                reject();
            }
            else {
                _timer = setTimeout(check, 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    check();

  }).then(function() {
    clearTimeout(_timer);
  });
}
```